# Is there more elegant way to deploy laravel app in docker

Tags: laravel, docker, alpine-linux

After many attempt to tidy up my laravel docker deployment, i've come with the Dockerfile below. But still, my image is still over 2Gb in size, which is enormous. Is there any thing I can do to optimize my final image size?
Heres is my Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:latest

WORKDIR /var/www/html/

# Essentials
RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata
ENV TZ=Asia/Jakarta

RUN apk add --no-cache zip unzip curl nginx supervisor

# Installing bash
RUN apk add bash
RUN sed -i 's/bin\/ash/bin\/bash/g' /etc/passwd

# Installing PHP
RUN apk add --no-cache php82 \
    php82-common \
    php82-fpm \
    php82-pdo \
    php82-opcache \
    php82-zip \
    php82-gd \
    php82-phar \
    php82-iconv \
    php82-cli \
    php82-curl \
    php82-openssl \
    php82-mbstring \
    php82-exif \
    php82-tokenizer \
    php82-fileinfo \
    php82-json \
    php82-xml \
    php82-xmlreader \
    php82-xmlwriter \
    php82-simplexml \
    php82-dom \
    php82-pdo_mysql \
    php82-tokenizer \
    php82-pecl-redis

RUN ln -s /usr/bin/php82 /usr/bin/php

# Installing composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer -o composer-setup.php
RUN php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN rm -rf composer-setup.php

RUN apk add nodejs yarn

# Configure supervisor
RUN mkdir -p /etc/supervisor.d/
COPY ./docker/supervisor/supervisord.ini /etc/supervisor.d/supervisord.ini

# Configure PHP
RUN mkdir -p /run/php/
RUN touch /run/php/php8.2-fpm.pid

COPY ./docker/php/php-fpm.conf /etc/php82/php-fpm.conf
COPY ./docker/php/php.ini-production /etc/php82/php.ini

# Configure nginx
COPY ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
COPY ./docker/nginx/webserver.conf /etc/nginx/http.d/default.conf

RUN mkdir -p /run/nginx/
RUN touch /run/nginx/nginx.pid

RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log
RUN ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log

# Building process
COPY . .
RUN composer install
RUN chown -R nobody:nobody /var/www/html/storage
RUN yarn

# Run a cron job
ADD ./docker/cron/crontab.txt /crontab.txt
RUN /usr/bin/crontab /crontab.txt

# add log for supervisor laravel worker
RUN touch /var/www/html/storage/logs/worker.log

# Generate Laravel app encryption key
RUN cp .env.example .env
RUN php artisan key:generate --ansi
RUN php artisan vendor:publish --all

RUN chown -R nginx:nginx /var/www/html -v
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html -v
RUN chown -R nginx:nginx /var/lib/nginx -v
RUN chmod -R 755 /var/lib/nginx -v
RUN chmod -R 755 /var/log/nginx -v

# Exposing port 80 (http)
EXPOSE 80

# Auto start supervisor on start
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

I tried to do multi stage before but the result image is still fairly big in size.
did i miss some crucial step in creating my docker file?

Comment: My approach is usually to just use a Docker image to run the PHP side of things and then bind mount the Laravel app into the container, then just update those files on the host when needed.

Comment: The `RUN chown`/`RUN chmod` steps at the end will massively blow up your image size; also they're a bad idea (you do not want your application directory to be a place where a code bug would allow an attacker to overwrite your application and drop arbitrary executables).  Can you delete these?  Can you split the PHP, Nginx, and Node parts into separate images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some bit a research and thingkering, i found best method i could to reduce image size.
As said by @Denis Sinyukov, it's true that breaking down Dockerfile into multiple stage help reduce the size a lot, but more importantly if your app has fronted / fullstack laravel app, after you're done building your frontend style/javascript or else, you should delete node_module.
Here i completely get rid of frontend build stage, then continue to php stuff

```
FROM node:18.3.0-alpine as FrontendStage

COPY . /var/www/html
WORKDIR /var/www/html/

# Essentials
RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata
ENV TZ=Asia/Jakarta

RUN npm install
RUN npm run production
RUN npm run tailwind-production
RUN rm -rf /var/www/html/node_modules

FROM alpine:latest as BuildStage

WORKDIR /var/www/html/
COPY --from=FrontendStage /var/www/html /var/www/html/

RUN apk add --no-cache zip unzip curl nginx supervisor

# Installing bash
RUN apk add bash
RUN sed -i 's/bin\/ash/bin\/bash/g' /etc/passwd

# Installing PHP
RUN apk add --no-cache php82 \
    php82-common \
    php82-fpm \
    php82-pdo \
    php82-opcache \
    php82-zip \
    php82-gd \
    php82-phar \
    php82-iconv \
    php82-cli \
    php82-curl \
    php82-openssl \
    php82-mbstring \
    php82-exif \
    php82-tokenizer \
    php82-fileinfo \
    php82-json \
    php82-xml \
    php82-xmlreader \
    php82-xmlwriter \
    php82-simplexml \
    php82-dom \
    php82-pdo_mysql \
    php82-tokenizer \
    php82-pecl-redis

RUN ln -s /usr/bin/php82 /usr/bin/php

# Installing composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer -o composer-setup.php
RUN php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN rm -rf composer-setup.php

# Configure supervisor
RUN mkdir -p /etc/supervisor.d/
COPY ./docker/supervisor/supervisord.ini /etc/supervisor.d/supervisord.ini

# Configure PHP
RUN mkdir -p /run/php/
RUN touch /run/php/php8.2-fpm.pid

COPY ./docker/php/php-fpm.conf /etc/php82/php-fpm.conf
COPY ./docker/php/php.ini-production /etc/php82/php.ini

# Configure nginx
COPY ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
COPY ./docker/nginx/webserver.conf /etc/nginx/http.d/default.conf

RUN mkdir -p /run/nginx/
RUN touch /run/nginx/nginx.pid

RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log
RUN ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log

# Building process
COPY . .
RUN composer install
RUN chown -R nobody:nobody /var/www/html/storage

# Run a cron job
ADD ./docker/cron/crontab.txt /crontab.txt
RUN /usr/bin/crontab /crontab.txt

# add log for supervisor laravel worker
RUN touch /var/www/html/storage/logs/worker.log

# Generate Laravel app encryption key
RUN cp .env.example .env
RUN php artisan key:generate --ansi
RUN php artisan vendor:publish --all
RUN php artisan storage:link

RUN chown -R nginx:nginx /var/www/html -v
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html -v
RUN chown -R nginx:nginx /var/lib/nginx -v
RUN chmod -R 755 /var/lib/nginx -v
RUN chmod -R 755 /var/log/nginx -v

# Exposing port 80 (http)
EXPOSE 80

# Auto start supervisor on start
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

Answer (score 1):

- Each RUN command adds a new layer to your Docker image. Combine related commands into a single RUN statement where possible.
- Evaluate if every file added with COPY or ADD is necessary, or if they can be condensed. Use a `.dockerignore` file to ensure only necessary files are being added to the context and thus to the image.

Here is the modified version of your `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:latest as builder

WORKDIR /var/www/html/

RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata \
    zip \
    unzip \
    curl \
    nginx \
    supervisor \
    bash \
    nodejs \
    yarn \
    php82 \
    php82-common \
    php82-fpm \
    php82-pdo \
    php82-opcache \
    php82-zip \
    php82-gd \
    php82-phar \
    php82-iconv \
    php82-cli \
    php82-curl \
    php82-openssl \
    php82-mbstring \
    php82-exif \
    php82-tokenizer \
    php82-fileinfo \
    php82-json \
    php82-xml \
    php82-xmlreader \
    php82-xmlwriter \
    php82-simplexml \
    php82-dom \
    php82-pdo_mysql \
    php82-pecl-redis && \
    ln -s /usr/bin/php82 /usr/bin/php && \
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

COPY ./docker/php/php-fpm.conf /etc/php82/php-fpm.conf
COPY ./docker/php/php.ini-production /etc/php82/php.ini
COPY ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
COPY ./docker/nginx/webserver.conf /etc/nginx/http.d/default.conf
COPY ./docker/supervisor/supervisord.ini /etc/supervisor.d/supervisord.ini
COPY . .

RUN composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader && \
    yarn --production && \
    yarn cache clean && \
    rm -rf node_modules

FROM alpine:latest

WORKDIR /var/www/html/

COPY --from=builder /var/www/html /var/www/html
COPY --from=builder /etc/php82 /etc/php82
COPY --from=builder /etc/nginx /etc/nginx
COPY --from=builder /etc/supervisor.d/supervisord.ini /etc/supervisor.d/supervisord.ini
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer
COPY --from=builder /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php

RUN mkdir -p /run/php/ && \
    mkdir -p /run/nginx/ && \
    touch /run/php/php8.2-fpm.pid && \
    touch /run/nginx/nginx.pid && \
    ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log && \
    ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log && \
    chown -R nginx:nginx /var/www/html && \
    chmod -R 755 /var/www/html

RUN chown -R nobody:nobody /var/www/html/storage && \
    chown -R nginx:nginx /var/lib/nginx && \
    chmod -R 755 /var/lib/nginx && \
    chmod -R 755 /var/log/nginx

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add to the answer above. I would also put everything related to nginx into a separate container.

and also consider all the packages that are needed only for assembly and remove them later

```
RUN set -ex \
&& apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
&& .... all dev packages ...
.......................
&& apk del .build-deps \
&& rm -rf /tmp/* /var/cache/apk/*
```